# How to invoke Webview button clickevent in Android?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-webservice, android-websettings

I am developing an android app with a web app loading on WebView. I want to invoke the web app button actions. I have implemented some changes on webpage to invoke native methods as shown below.

mWebview.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {

```
        @JavascriptInterface // For API 17+
        public void callNativeHome() {

            Log.d("btnsetup", "btnsetup");

      

        }
    }, "btnsetup");
```

But now I can't make any changes on web end as it's not my web screen. How I can access the button click events by ID or class name?

Answer (score 0):

Web access is mandatory to **Bind JavaScript code to Android code.**

Android:

```
val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
webView.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this), "Android")
```

Web:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

You can simply follow [Bind JavaScript code to Android code.](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript)

---

Another workaround is to find the navigation URL. You can check/compare the redirection URL called after clicking that button.

For more information, you can check [Handle page navigation in webview.](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/webview#HandlingNavigation)